# std::move and corrupted map

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm currently trying to debug a heap corruption where one node of a std::map has been corrupted. The map is delivered by someone elses code and assigned to us via std::move.

My question is if the standard implementation of the move constructor for std::map ever has to iterate over the nodes and would thus segfault at a corrupted node.

Otherwise I'd replace the move by a regular copy constructor call in the hopes that it does have the behavior I need.

The code has been compiled with gcc 5.3.0.

Regards.

Comment: A move constructor for an `std::map` just reassigns some internal pointers. The standard requires `O(1)` time complexity for it. Same for move assignment.

Comment: Ok. But copy constructor is guaranteed to walk over every node so a defect pointer is likely to segfault?

Comment: A defect pointer is UB, and with UB you have no guarantees.

Comment: The defect pointer usually segfaults if I iterate over the map with a regular iterator. Does the copy constructor use the same parent/child pointers the iterator uses?

Comment: Implementations are not specified, but I would suppose it does.

Comment: Ok, thank you. If you turn this into an answer I can give you hook.

Comment: I'd prefer to leave as a comment.